# k=n-1 in recurrence relations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

When using the iterative technique when solving for recurrence relations, why do we set k= n-1? What allows us to set it to this value and why do we do this?[image]

Comment: You’ll need to give more context; it isn’t clear what you’re asking. An example of what you mean would be most helpful.

Comment: Hi Brian, I added a screenshot of a problem I was working on. My teacher says its to relate An and A1, but it doesn't make a lot of sense to me how to know when to do this/why

Comment: It starts at an implicit relationship between $a_n$ and $a_{n-1}$, to arrive an explicit formula of $a_n$, it's looking for the relationship between $a_n$ and $a_1$ (as the green notes said), as $a_1$ is known. By deduction it has a relationship between $a_n$ and $a_{n-k}$, so if you can find $k$ to make $n-k$ is actually $1$, then you are done. To achieve that, it just needs $k=n-1$.

Answer (score 1):

Recursion relations are sensitive to initial conditions, which is to say the state that you start in can change the outcome you receive. For example the Fibonacci numbers are typically defined with $a_1=0$ and $a_2=1$ but if we chose $a_2=4$ we would get a very different sequences by applying the relation $a_n=a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}$ because $0+1=1$ while $0+4=4$, a number which is never a Fibonacci number.

However once you establish what those initial conditions are the sequence is entirely formulaic and forced to be what they are by those numbers. In the case you've given we have a single number as an initial condition $a_1=11$. We can now describe every other number in the sequence based on that $a_1$. For example $a_4=a_3+3=(a_2+3)+3=((a_1+3)+3)+3$. At each step I make a substitution of the relation but with the index dropping by one. Our goal is to avoid doing this one step at a time and instead jump the queue and just get the the answer directly. If I can correctly calculate $a_n$ when given $a_{n-k}$ and can just set $n-k=1$ and get the full expression for $a_n$. Since $n-k=1$ implies that $k=n-1$ you make that substitution and it solves the expression in terms of the initial conditions given by $a_1$.

Comment: that makes a bit more sense. How do we know not to do k-n = 1?

Comment: actually I believe Athos' comment cleared that up - I believe it has to do with deduction - is that correct?

Comment: @Isabelle: You want to choose $k$ so that $n-k$ is the subscript of your initial value. Had you been given $a_0$ instead of $a_1$ as the initial value, you’d have set $k=n$, so that $n-k=0$. Had you been given $a_2$ as the initial value, you’d have set $k=n-2$, so that $n-k=2$.